# Splitting strings on an nth character in Python

Tags: python, split, slice

I would like to know how to slice my Python string every nth character/letter (in my case the 5th character/letter).

So I have this string `"ilikestackoverflow"` and I would like for the output to be `"ilike stack overf low"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 x = zip(*[iter(my_array)]*5)
```

is a cool but hard to read way of doing it

typically it is done with a list comprehension though

```
n = 5
x = [my_array[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(my_array),n)]
```

this post explains the `iter` answer best  http://www.stavros.io/posts/brilliant-or-insane-code/

Comment: could you please explain how this works?

Comment: chicken blood and pentagrams

Comment: where did i come from?

Comment: `for i in BLAH` creates a locally scoped i ... its standard list comprehension stuff

Answer (score 1):

What about a good-ol' regular expression?

```
>>> string = "Ireallylovemyregularexpressions!"
>>> print re.sub(r'(.{5})', r'\1 ', string)
Ireal lylov emyre gular expre ssion s!
```

`(.{5})` matches every 5 characters, `r'\1 '` replaces these 5 characters by the same 5 characters plus a white-space character.

---

This also works:

```
>>> m = re.split(r'(.{5})', 'Ilovestackoverflowsobad')
>>> print m
['', 'Ilove', '', 'stack', '', 'overf', '', 'lowso', 'bad']
>>> for word in m:
...     if word == '':
...         pass
...     else:
...         print word,
... 
Ilove stack overf lowso bad
```

Comment: +1 although this reminds me about that saying "I had a problem, and I thought 'I know Ill use regular expressions' ..."

Comment: Haha, yeah, I agree, but I was studying regular expressions, and you know: if you have a hammer, every problem starts looking like a nail.